# Problem with Rasterize tool (Vector to Raster)

Tags: qgis, raster, rasterization

I am not able to rasterize shp file with Rasterize tool. I keep getting this error :

> Could not reproject layer extent: Could not transform bounding box to
> target CRS.

I have selected following parameters:

- input layer: shp file
- output raster size units: pixels
- width and height: same as raster
- output extent: raster file
- output data type: same as raster(byte), tried putting int,float32 but
  no change
- rasterized: saved as a tif file

Comment: Obviously there's something "wrong" with your CRS. Which one are you using?

Comment: @Erik for shp:- Default CRS: EPSG:4326-WGS 84
for tif:- EPSG:32606-WGS 84 /UTM Zone 6N

Comment: Which extent does your shapefile have?

Comment: You probably have values beyond the expected -180, 180, -90, 90 boundaries of the WGS84. Maybe your data is not really in 4326?

Comment: @Erik 
shp Extent:-
-147.4958466764738318,65.1294385784811993 : -147.4768937754956823,65.1354042941769791
tif Extent:- 476690.6698999999789521,7222409.4579999996349216 : 477996.2334000000264496,7223816.8580000000074506

Comment: @AlexandreNeto wdym by that? How do I check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use a raster in a different CRS as a reference for the output extent, because for WGS84 the raster's extents make no sense.

Use the projection tool to convert your vector data into EPSG:32606, then use the rasterize tool.